# MAUI BindingContext does not work when set to a Binding

Tags: listview, data-binding, maui

On my main page I have a MainViewModel that contains some properties, one of which is EffectsCtrl (another view model, instance of EffectsControl class), which contains some logic associated with managing the list of effects. To display this list I have the following ListView on my main page:

```
<ContentPage
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Effects"
  x:Class="Effects.MainPage"
  xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Effects.ViewModel"
  x:DataType="vm:MainViewModel">
  ...
  <ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding EffectsCtrl.Effects}"
    HasUnevenRows="True"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      ...
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

The above works fine - list properly displays and updates on changes.

But at some point I changed it to this

```
<ListView
  BindingContext={Binding EffectsCtrl}
  ItemsSource="{Binding Effects}"
  HasUnevenRows="True"
  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
  ...
</ListView>
```

and to my great surprise I was shown a tip by my IDE (Visual Studio) that Effects 'Member not found in data context MainViewModel' and upon launching the build failed with an error 'Binding: Property "Effects" not found on "Effects.ViewModel.MainViewModel"'.
At this point I was a little confused and curious so I tried some other combinations like

```
<ListView
  BindingContext={Binding EffectsCtrl}
  ItemsSource="{Binding EffectsCtrl.Effects}"
  HasUnevenRows="True"
  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
  ...
</ListView>
```

and this compiles fine without warnings from IDE or build errors but the list does not display at all - I assume due to wrong binding because I checked the EffectsCtrl in debugger and everything is fine and elements are added to the list as usual. Also there are no warnings or errors displayed by the debugger.

And this brings me to my question: is this a bug or do I misunderstand something about binding? When I was making the first change I assumed that when I change the ListView's BindingContext it will affect the binding on its ItemsSource field. And I'm even more confused because the 3rd case seems to somewhat confirm my assumption. So can someone confirm this is a bug or provide me with an explanation why the 2nd case is invalid?

EDIT:
I did some more testing and when `x:DataType="vm:MainViewModel"` from the ContentPage declaration is removed the 2nd case works as intended. Why is that?

Comment: `BindingContext` does not work like that, the thing you did first was the correct way, don't change it

Comment: @FreakyAli can you please explain in more detail why is the first way the correct one, why does this not work like that or how does it work? Or where can I find the answer to my questions? Because official documentation (data binding basics and MVVM) provide little information about this.

Comment: Well think of BindingContext as a class that holds your Model as actual data and your Commands and Stuff, Now Binding acts as a One-One Mapping, So you need to Bind the Same type of Property to the Same TYPE of Control property. So assume you Bind your View(Page) with a ViewModel(BindingContext) it basically distributes this Mapping to its children, So Assume this Page of your has a ContentView and You had an Object in your ViewModel If you wanted to Assign an object to another object what would you do? you would do something like MyListSource = ViewModel.ItemSource Right?

Comment: Now if you wanted to convert the above Object mapping to a Binding you would do something like this. `MyListSource= "{Binding ViewModel.Itemsource}"` Hope this helped you :)

Comment: @FreakyAli thank you for a more detailed explanation but I think this is not the case. EffectsCtrl is a ViewModel by itself (probably the name is misleading), it is stored in MainViewModel and it contains the Effects ObservableCollection which is bound to the ListView.ItemsSource. But because it is used as the MainViewModel's property I couldn't reference it directly from the ListView.DataTemplate by using ```RelativeSource AncestorType```. And that's why I wanted to bind the EffectsCtrl to the ListView.BindingContext and ```Effects``` instead of ```EffectsCtrl.Effects``` to ItemsSource.

Comment: @FreakyAli And I understand the concept of binding and types matching that comes with it. The thing I want to do is doable as I prove it in my edit - when you remove the ```x:DataType="vm:MainViewModel"``` from ContentPage the list works as intended in case 2.

Comment: Your problem is Architecture rather than a bunch of Properties, ViewModel will never be a property of Another ViewModel, The whole concept of MVVM is to make code as less interdependent to each other as possible, to increase testability, if you have nested ViewModels it basically breaks the whole purpose

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248807/discussion-between-freakyali-and-shin-qdan).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer myself in the [Compiled bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings) documentation. It turns out the `x:DataType="vm:MainViewModel"` is the problem, although this behavior is absolutely correct and the problem is due to my misunderstanding. This attribute set on the `ContentPage` causes the compilation of the bindings. And as the abovementioned documentation states

> Set an x:DataType attribute on a VisualElement to the type of the object that the VisualElement and its children will bind to.

This means that every element in the `ContentPage` is expected to have `BindingContext` set to an instance of MainViewModel (unless another `x:DataType` attribute says otherwise, I assume). Therefore when binding to `Effects` is used in the 2nd case, even though `BindingContext` is set to EffectsCtrl, the compiler throws an error - it assumes the `BindingContext` will be an instance of MainViewModel (and not EffectsControl instance) and it indeed does not contain the `Effects` property.

I came with 2 possible solutions to this:

#### 1st solution:

Just switch to the runtime validation by removing the `x:DataType="vm:MainViewModel"` from the `ContentPage` attributes. But such an action has some negative consequences - you lose the compile-time bindings validation, the runtime validation impacts performance and the IDE won't provide auto-completion (at least Visual Studio).
The code then looks like this:

```
<ContentPage
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Effects"
  x:Class="Effects.MainPage"
  xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Effects.ViewModel">
  ...
  <ListView
    BindingContext="{Binding EffectsCtrl}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Effects}"
    HasUnevenRows="True"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      ...
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

The MainViewModel is passed by dependency injection and everything works fine.

#### 2nd solution:

To keep the compiled bindings I just added the `x:DataType="vm:EffectsControl"` attribute to the `ListView` but then I couldn't use the `BindingContext="{Binding EffectsCtrl}"` attribute because there is no EffectsCtrl property in the EffectsCtrl itself. So instead of that I wrapped the `ListView` in a new `ContentView` class like this:

```
<ContentView 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  x:Class="Effects.EffectsListView"
  xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Effects.ViewModel"
  x:DataType="vm:EffectsControl">

  <ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Effects}"
    HasUnevenRows="True"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      ...
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</ContentView>
```

and replaced the list on the main page with the new class

```
<ContentPage
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Effects"
  x:Class="Effects.MainPage"
  xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Effects.ViewModel"
  x:DataType="vm:MainViewModel">
  ...
  <local:EffectsListView BindingContext="{Binding EffectsCtrl}"/>
</ContentPage>
```

I find this behavior not very intuitive but now as I understand the concept I think this question is a bit silly. Anyway I hope this helps some lost beginner like myself.

Comment: Make sure to use  <ViewCell> as well

Comment: The content of the ListView doesn't matter in this case. It can be any type of cell - not only but also ViewCell.

Answer (score 1):

The `ListView` item template will bind to the type of the list, however as I found also, classes in other locations will confuse the compile-time validation of the bindings.

I'm not sure that this is exactly your scenario, but I solved it by adding a "XAML Namespace" declaration `xmlns`:

```
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
    xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
    xmlns:m="clr-namespace:My.Assembly.Namespace;assembly=My.Assembly"
```

Then I could add the `DataType` to the item template:

```
<ListView x:Name="searchResults" ItemsSource="{Binding Results}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="m:ResultDto">
            <TextCell Text="{Binding Code}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In this scenario, `Results` is an enumerable on my View Model, but ResultDto is a class in `My.Assembly.Namespace` with the property `Code`.

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings
- the xmlns doco: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/markup-extensions
- relative bindings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings

Comment: The `ItemTemplate` `DataType` is working fine and is not the case here. It was the `BindingContext` of the `ListView` that was problematic. In the end it turned out the compilation of the bindings was the issue. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74072876/9553440) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in MAUI (as of March 2024).

Once you set a new `BindingContext` on a child view (such as the ListView in your example), any other Bindable Properties on that child view (ListView) will attempt to bind with the child's `BindingContext`, NOT the Page's `BindingContext`.  HOWEVER, the XAML still thinks you are trying to bind with the Page's `BindingContext` and it will give you an error if you try to reference a property on the child `BindingContext` that is not also on the Page `BindingContext`.

If you need to bind to the property on the child's `BindingContext`, an easy (but ugly) work around is to create a matching property on the parent `BindingContext`.  It will not bind to it, but it will allow the XAML to compile.

If you are ok moving that property off of the child and onto the parent `BindingContext`, you can access the property by adding `Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type models:YourParentViewModel}}` to your binding to tell XAML that you are not trying to bind to the child view's but to the parent/page's `BindingContext`.

Answer (score 0):

See [Data binding basics / view-to-view bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/data-binding-basics#view-to-view-bindings). Use `x:Reference` to an element's `x:Name`.

If your EffectsCtrl has x:Name `myEffectsCtrl`, then do:

```xml
<EffectsCtrl x:Name="myEffectsCtrl" ... />
<ListView
  BindingContext="{x:Reference myEffectsCtrl}" ... />
```

Comment: EffectsCtrl is a ViewModel, it is not present in the XAML, it is passed through dependency injection so ```x:Reference``` is not an option. Also I read the [Data binding basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/data-binding-basics) and [Data binding and MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/mvvm) as well as the [Data binding in fundamentals section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/) but none of these provide sufficient information on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the x:DataType to x:DataType="{x:Null}" in your ListView

```
<ContentPage
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Effects"
  x:Class="Effects.MainPage"
  xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Effects.ViewModel"
  x:DataType="vm:MainViewModel">
  ...
<ListView
  x:DataType="{x:Null}"
  BindingContext={Binding EffectsCtrl}
  ItemsSource="{Binding Effects}"
  HasUnevenRows="True"
  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
  ...
</ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings?view=net-maui-8.0